# How to distort an image according to a four-sided polygon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, my user can take a picture and get an image file.

My user can then place 4 points anywhere in the image, so he gets a four-sided polygon.

What I would like to do is allow the user to move those 4 points at each corner of the image, so that the portion of the image *inside* the polygon is distorted accordingly.

Here is a visual example:

- the original image, with 4 points placed by the user:

[image: original image with 4 points]

- the final image, distorted according to the polygon, where each point of the polygon has been moved to the corner of the image:

[image]

I guess I'll have to use a `CustomPainter` to achieve that, but I don't now how to do that and I can't find any tutorial on that.

So how can I distort my image?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `copyRectify()` function of the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package was what I was looking for.

More info [here](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/blob/main/doc/transform.md).